# How to handle invalid routing in polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In this case https://localhost/invalid/ I can catch the event at polymer app-router and redirect to customized 404 html page.

In this case https://localhost/invalid.txt I can't catch the event at polymer app-router. server will look for the file and throws an error ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/usr/src/app/build/bundled/invalid.txt'

How can i handle and re-route it.

Comment: Are you serving your app with the Polymer serve command or do you use your own server ? If you are always serving your index file the app-router should handle the rest

Comment: I am doing polymer serve through command line.

Comment: Maybe you could update your answer and show some of your code. In particular the routing in your app-shell. Or is it just the basic Polymer app from the CLI.